# Invoking function of a returned object from function prints undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

```
var unique = function(){

var n=0;
return function(){

    return {

        inc : function(){
            n++;
            console.log(n);
        }

    };

 };
};

console.log(unique()().inc());
```

The code above prints 1 and then undefined what is the reason undefined gets printed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you asked to log the value returned by `inc`, and it doesn't return anything.

If you don't want to print anything,

```
console.log(unique()().inc());
```

should be

```
unique()().inc();
```

If you expect the new value of `n` to be printed,

```
inc : function(){ n++; console.log(n); }
```

should be

```
inc : function(){ n++; console.log(n); return n; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 console.log, one inside inc (that prints 1), the other in the last line, (that prints undefined).

You can add  `return n;` after the first `console` inside `inc`

```
    inc : function(){
        n++;
        console.log(n);
        return n;
    }
```